# How to overide CSS for width?

Tags: html, css

How do I override the default width of UL? For example:

```
.tabPage .tabs ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:149px !important; 
    margin-top: 10px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

So html would look like this:

```
<div class="tabPage">
      <div class="tabs">
         <ul> <li> ... </li> <ul>
      </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to change the width size to 50px for `UL` for different webpage.

I have tried like this:

```
  .TabWidthSmall { width:149px; }
```

I have put this selector in the `<ul>` and it did not work.

Comment: For reference, `!important` is evil.  For exactly this reason, among others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
.tabPage .tabs ul.TabWidthSmall {
    width:50px  !important; /* put new width here */
}
```

Comment: You added `class="TabWidthSmall"` to your `ul` and it still didn't work?  What do you see if you inspect the `ul` with Firebug or a similar tool?  It should show you which styles are getting applied and what the source was for those styles.

Comment: As you can see in http://jsfiddle.net/CrqYc/ that should work! and if not, the problem is in another place. Please put more peaces of your code, in Q to get help.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need the `!important` ? The rules in CSS cascade down, using `!important` halts this process. If you set a width on your parent `ul` and set another width on any subsequent children `ul` - assuming the css selectors are correct - this will get picked up and will be applied to your element.

Alternatively, as @Javad_Amiry mentioned you can also use `!important` on your children `ul` to override the previous `!important`, but I would try and stay clear of using so many `!important`'s as it is a sign of bad design.

Comment: Agreed. Why is there an !important in `.tabPage .tabs ul`, there your problem.